# Multiple inheritance: The derived class gets attributes from one base class only?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I was trying to learn the concepts of multiple-inheritance in Python. Consider a class `Derv` derived from two classes, `Base1` and `Base2`. `Derv` inherits members from the first base class only:

```
class Base1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=10

class Base2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y=10

class Derv (Base1, Base2):
    pass

d = Derv()
print (d.__dict__)
```

The result is `{ 'x' : 10 }` and reversing the order of inheritance gives only `{ 'y' : 10 }`.

Shouldn't the derived class inherit attributes from both the base classes?

Comment: hint: `x` and `y` are not class attributes.  `__init__`, however, is.

Comment: so what are x and y

Comment: It is accurate enough to say `x` and `y` are instance attributes?

Comment: And instance attributes are not inherited? I don't really understand, coming from a mixed C++, Java, C# background, how does this relate. Can you give an elaborate answer...

Comment: just: inheritance is a relationship classes can have with other classes, not instances of them—although the latter's behavior can be affected by the any such connections their class has.

Comment: but instances get attributes from their classes, so when a class inherits from another, instance of derived class should have all attributes from its base class(es)

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand why it's like this, but I can tell you how to fix it:

For some reason, Python only calls the `__init__` method of one of it's parents. However, this fixes your problem:

```
class Base1:
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         print('b1')
         self.x=10

 class Base2:
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__() # This line isn't needed. Still not sure why
         print('b2')
         self.y=10

 class Derv (Base1, Base2):

     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()

 d = Derv()
 print (d.__dict__)


'b2'
'b1'
{'y': 10, 'x': 10}
```

---

Update, adding print statements actually sheds some light on the situation. For example,

```
class Base1:
     def __init__(self):
         print('Before Base1 call to super()')
         super().__init__()
         print('b1')
         self.x=10

 class Base2:
     def __init__(self):
         print('Before Base2 call to super()')
         super().__init__() # No remaining super classes to call
         print('b2')
         self.y=10

 class Derv (Base1, Base2):

     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()

 d = Derv()
 print (d.__dict__)

'Before Base1 call to super()' # Just before the call to super
'Before Base2 call to super()' # Just before call to super (but there are no more super classes)
'b2' # Calls the remaining super's __init__
'b1' # Finishes Base1 __init__
{'y': 10, 'x': 10}
```

Comment: so does calling super().__init__() call init on all the base classes. What exactly does super() return?

Comment: I think it just calls the first super's `__init__` method

Comment: Folks, suggest you read [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) by guru Raymond Hettinger.

Answer (score 2):

When a class inherits from multiple superclasses, and there are 2 or more conflicting methods, the one in the first listed class is called. Because both `Base1` and `Base2` define `__init__`, the version of `__init__` in the first listed class is called, therefore not defining both of the attributes.

Comment: Great, I understand this is because of MRO. But how does the call to super().__init__ call init from both the base classes. And what does super() return!

Comment: It's more reliable to use the syntax `SuperclassName.__init__(self, ...)`, which calls the superclass constructor for the specified superclass.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

This is explained better in [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance).

> For most purposes, in the simplest cases, you can think of the search
>   for attributes inherited from a parent class as depth-first,
>   left-to-right, **not searching twice in the same class where there is an
>   overlap in the hierarchy**. Thus, if an attribute is not found in
>   DerivedClassName, it is searched for in Base1, then (recursively) in
>   the base classes of Base1, and if it was not found there, it was
>   searched for in Base2, and so on.

Then, as `__init__` is first find in your left class, it won't look for others. As other users explained, `super()` should be used to let Python know how to look for other `__init__` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could create objects with class attributes like this:

```
class Base1:
    x=10

class Base2:
    y=10
```

Then your Derv class would indeed inherit both properties.

```
class Derv (Base1, Base2):
    pass

d = Derv()
print(d.x, d.y)  # prints: 10, 10
```

The `__init__` method is called when you create an instance of an object (ie, `d = Derv()`). An object can only have one version of a given method, so your Derv class only inherits the first one.

Comment: I do understand this after reading the received answers. But, now the confusion is how is super().__init__() calling init from both the base classes.

Comment: In general, `super()` calls the `__init__` method of the parent class. In the case of multiple inheritance, it should call the `__init__` method of the first parent (listed left to right) with this method defined. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance