# Issue with inherited attributes in a class with multiple base classes

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

EDIT:
Thanks for the information about the class attributes. I understand these are similar to static in other OO languages. Now in the following code, I wish to use the `__init__` of the base classes to set `x` and `y` in the derived class. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
class Base1:
  def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x

class Base2:
  def __init__(self, y):
      self.y = y

class Derv (Base1, Base2):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
```

OLD:

Related to [Multiple inheritance: The derived class gets attributes from one base class only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959041/multiple-inheritance-the-derived-class-gets-attributes-from-one-base-class-only)

Now, what is happening in the following example (dictionary of d is empty):

```
class Base1:
  x = 10

class Base2:
  y = 10

class Derv (Base1, Base2):
  pass


d=Derv()
print (d.__dict__)
```

Although this works when we change the code to following:

```
class Base1:
  x = 0
  def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x

class Base2:
  y = 0
  def __init__(self, y):
      self.y = y

class Derv (Base1, Base2):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
```

I think this is more because of defining `x and y` in the `__init__` method of `Derv`. But, if I wish to set the values using base class constructors, what is the correct way?

Comment: Your two base classes both have a class attribute and an instance attribute with the same name—which is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Martineau. Exacerbated by the fact that OP isn't using parent constructors properly.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for the correct syntax to invoke the base class constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest and best: just call the initializers in each base!

```
class Derv(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Base1.__init__(self, x)
        Base2.__init__(self, y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I was looking for. Tried using super().__init__(), but couldn't get the required results.